# Mongo DB Facets Query and Filter

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have been trying some queries and had an issue so posting here for some help.

here is a sample JSON how it looks like

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f82cb362ce0b715157bf903"
    },
    "show_id": 81145628,
    "type": "Movie",
    "title": "Norm of the North: King Sized Adventure",
    "director": "Richard Finn, Tim Maltby",
    "cast": "Alan Marriott, Andrew Toth, Brian Dobson, Cole Howard, Jennifer Cameron, Jonathan Holmes, Lee Tockar, Lisa Durupt, Maya Kay, Michael Dobson",
    "country": "United States, India, South Korea, China",
    "date_added": "9-Sep-19",
    "release_year": 2019,
    "rating": "TV-PG",
    "duration": "90 min",
    "listed_in": "Children & Family Movies, Comedies",
    "description": "Before planning an awesome wedding for his grandfather, a polar bear king must take back a stolen artifact from an evil archaeologist first."
}
```

Here is my query

```
query = [

    {
        "$facet": {
            "Title": [
                {
                    "$unwind": "$title"
                },
                {
                    "$sortByCount": "$title"
                },
                {
                    "$limit": 7
                },
            ]
        }
    }
]

CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb://root:rootpassword@localhost:27017"
client = MongoClient(host=CONNECTION_URL)
d = client['movies']['movie'].aggregate(query1)
for x in d:
    print(x)
```

This works fine, but I want to filter out and do aggregation go an aggregation where movie title starts with n* something like that. I tried a few options that seem to be not working. Any help would be great.

Comment: (1) `"$unwind": "$title"` - `$unwind` is used with fields of type _array_; it doesn't apply in your case. Also, note the `$facet` stage is useful if your aggregation has multiple facets - you are better off _not_using it in the above query. (2) To query the movies that start with a character or a string you can use the [regex query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html#examples).

Comment: First of all thank you for taking out time and commenting on it. yes i did use regexp query i was just curious to know if we could do with facets but based on your explanation it seems i will go ahead and use regexp queries

Comment: you have given input collection JSON, this is helpful. Please provide the expected outcome to your query.